# Eliminating calendar view on Nikon D780

Tags: nikon, display

After each exposure the calendar view shows up on the screen. Playback display options does nothing to remedy this. I would like to see the image I just took without having to take an additional step in the heat of action. I'd like to have some advice on this issue.

Comment: Have you just zoomed out to calender view? With an image displayed, press on the + magnifying glass button several times until you're back to the normal view. I think that's the only way to change the view screen's zoom level, recognizing that I could be mistaken.